# Azure AD Authentication With Auth0

Tags: c#, azure, active-directory, oauth-2.0, auth0

I created an Azure API App and set the `[Authorize]` attribute on my controller and published it to Azure. Then I registered an Auth0 app, providing the data from my AD app, following [Auth0's documentation](https://auth0.com/docs/connections/enterprise/azure-active-directory). When I test the connection on their site it works just fine. I can also log in fine in my app and retrieve the access token with:

```
var auth0 = new Auth0Client("myUrl", "myTenant");
var user = await auth0.LoginAsync();
var accessToken = user.IdToken;
```

However, when I make a request to my API, passing the access token in the `Authorization` header, it just throws an error 401 (Unauthorized). From what the documentation says, I was under the impression this is all that should be needed, and I've not found any information to suggest otherwise. Is there an additional step to linking these?

Comment: Have u configured ur API to accept tokens by that issuer? Like for example by using owin middleware (app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication) ?

Comment: @Helikaon Oh duh... Looks like they covered that in the *other* tutorial that I didn't think to look over. That fixed it. If you put it as an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Solution is to configure ur API to accept tokens by that issuer, like for example by using owin middleware app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(). Glad I could help!